# best way to upload many bitmaps to server

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have an android app which let the user to submit a form , now this form can have 9 bitmaps (MAX). now my code run well , but it takes too long to upload the images . is there a better way to upload images ??

my code :

```
Iterator<String> it = car_images.iterator();
                int i = 0;
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    String imagepath = it.next();
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
                    b.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
                    byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
                    entity.addPart("image_" + i, new ByteArrayBody(data,

                    "myImage.jpg"));
                    Log.d("image loaded", "image_" + i);
                    ++i;

                }
                put.setEntity(entity);
                HttpResponse repsone = client.execute(put);
```

Comment: Yes. Don't use bitmap format.

Comment: what to use then ?? i dont understand you , please i am new to programming and have no experience

Comment: You could change the Bitmap quality to 90 instead of 100, as a temporary fix.  The reason JPEG compression is lossy compression is so you can lower the image quality slightly to achieve much higher compression than lossless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run the upload tasks in parallel using Threads, which could speedup the upload. Android developer's guide has good documentation (with sample code) available on [Threads and process](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html).